# Show then Hide in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make an explosion appear and then disappear. My problem is it will either appear, and stay there, or not appear at all.

This is what I have so far:

```
#Throwing a grenade
        if event.key == pygame.K_e and grenadeNum > 0:
            Grenade = Explosive([Player.rect.centerx, Player.rect.centery])
            for i in range(4, 30):
                Grenade.move()
                screen.fill([105, 105, 105])
                screen.blit(Grenade.image, Grenade.rect)
                screen.blit(Gun.image, Gun.rect)
                screen.blit(Cliper.image, Cliper.rect)
                screen.blit(Bullet.image, Bullet.rect)
                screen.blit(Player.image, Player.rect)
                screen.blit(BOOM.image, BOOM.rect)
                screen.blit(ammo_text, textpos1)
                screen.blit(clip_text, textpos2)
                screen.blit(nade_text, textpos3)
                pygame.display.update()
            grenadeNum = grenadeNum - 1
            explosion_sound.play()
            hide = False
            clock.tick(4)
            BOOM = Explosion([Grenade.rect.centerx, Grenade.rect.centery])
            screen.blit(BOOM.image, BOOM.rect)
                            hide = True


if hide == False:
    BOOM = Explosion([Grenade.rect.centerx, Grenade.rect.centery])
else:
    BOOM = Explosion([-100, -100])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are blitting and waiting inside the event loop.
Any actions will be suspended while waiting.

The solution to this is to seperate the game logic from input.
Since you are throwing a grenade, you should only throw the grenade, and then later increment a counter for the grenade explosion. After enought time passes, you can then remove the grenade sprite from the game, and replace it with an explosion. I can see you already have a clock object, so just call tick, and accumulate that until you think it's enough. You could have a time field in the grenade class that will decide when the grenade will explode.

It's useful to keep all sprites in a list, so you can then call draw() and update() methods for all of them.

A little suggestion: A simple pygame module should look like this:

```
createObjects() #initialization, loading resources etc.
while(True):
    delta = c.tick() #delta for the amount of miliseconds that passed since last loop
    drawAll() #draws all active sprites
    updateAll(delta) #moves, checks for collisions, etc
    getInput() #changes the states of objects, calls functions like shoot,open etc.
```

So throwing a grenade would create a new sprite that will be drawn and updated like any other sprite.